# How do I populate mongo repositories automatically?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Using Spring Data MongoDB with MongoRepository. I have this bean

```
@Bean
public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean repositoryPopulator() {

    Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
    try {
        factory.setResources(resourceResolver.getResources("classpath:static/collections/*.json"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Could not load data", e);
    }
    return factory;
}
```

which just works fine with [fongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo) (db is dropped at the end of a test run) but not with real mongo. If I leave the bean as it is and I switch to real mongo instance, then I get my data base populated but only the first run, if I re-run the project (+tests) then it fails because it's already populated (getting DuplicateKeyException).

How do I populate only on the case the repositories are empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Bean
public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean repositoryPopulator() throws Exception {

    Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
    try {
        Resource[] resources = resourceResolver.getResources("classpath:static/collections/*.json");
        //resources to list so I can add only the necessary resources
        List<Resource> resourcesToFill = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Resource r : resources) {
            String collection = r.getFilename().substring(0, r.getFilename().length() - 5);
            if (!mongoTemplate().collectionExists(collection))
                resourcesToFill.add(r);
        }

        //back to Array...
        resources = new Resource[resourcesToFill.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<resources.length; i++)
            resources[i] = resourcesToFill.get(i);
        factory.setResources(resources); // <-- the reason of this shitty code, why the hell use Array? 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Could not load data", e);
    }
    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using data migration tools like [Mongobee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee). This is basically Liquibase/Flyway for MongoDB.

Comment: Flyway now supports migrations for MongoDB in V10.1.0 a tutorial on how to use this functionality can be found here https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/tutorial-using-mongodb-with-flyway-225609601.html